# KnockoutJS 3: Minimizing repeating code between viewModels

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I am getting requests to let other people see my code and have been doing alot of cleanup, commenting and making things more readable and efficient in general, but I am having major difficulties with my KnockoutJS viewModels.

Basically I have 1 main `viewModel` and multiple `subModels` that all pull JSON data from different URLs and then i map them with `ko.mapping` plugin. In addition to that I have implemented `isDrity` on each `subModel` using Ryan Niemeyer's examples, plus some additional functions to save, reset and clear `isDirty` flag on the object properties. So, this results in repeating code in each `subModel` and I would like to have it cleaned up.

```
var viewModel = {

  subModel1 = ko.observable(),
  subModel2 = ko.observable(),
  subModel3 = ko.observable(),
  subModel4 = ko.observable(),
  subModel5 = ko.observable(),
  subModel6 = ko.observable(),

}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel)

// subModel1 Stuff
$.getJSON('/admin/getusers.json', function(data) {
  var mapping1 = { /* Mapping code here */ }
  var mappedModel1 = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping1);


  // REPEATING BLOCK
  allDirtyItems1 = ko.computed(function() {
    /* Some Code Here */
  });

  countDirtyItems1 = ko.computed(function() {
    /* Some Code Here */
  });

  resetEdits1 = function() {
    /* Some Code Here */
  }

  saveEdits1 = function() {
    /* Some Code Here */
  }
  // END OF REPEATING BLOCK

  uniqueFunction1 = functon() {
    /* Some Code Here */
  }

  uniqueFunction2 = functon() {
    /* Some Code Here */
  }  

  viewModel.subModel1(mappedModel1)

}

// subModel2 Stuff
$.getJSON('/admin/getdeployments.json', function(data) {
  var mapping2 = { /* Mapping code here */ }
  var mappedModel2 = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping2);


  // REPEATING BLOCK
  allDirtyItems2 = ko.computed(function() {
    /* Some Code Here */
  });

  countDirtyItems2 = ko.computed(function() {
    /* Some Code Here */
  });

  resetEdits2 = function() {
    /* Some Code Here */
  }

  saveEdits2 = function() {
    /* Some Code Here */
  }
  // END OF REPEATING BLOCK

  someOtherUniqueFunction1 = functon() {
    /* Some Code Here */
  }

  someOtherUniqueFunction2 = functon() {
    /* Some Code Here */
  }  

  viewModel.subModel2(mappedModel2)

}
```

I have tried using `ko.utils.extend`, but that does not seem to be working with `subModels` created by `ko.mapping` plugin because the resulting `subModel` is just an array of my JSON data from the server.

```
var sharedFunctions = function() {

    sharedFunction1 = function() {
        console.log('Hello, world!');
    }

}

ko.utils.extend(mappedModel1, sharedFunctions);
viewModel.subModel1(mappedModel1)
```

I have also tried using some sort of `baseViewModel` moving repeating code in there and then inheriting its properties into the `subModels`, but that does not seem to work with `ko.computed()`, because they only fire up once when I initialize the `subModel` and don't update after that.

Also, the way my code is structured, I am forced to do `allDirtyItems1`, `allDirtyItems2`, `allDirtyItems3`, etc. Instead of just having the same `allDirtyItems` property in each `subModel`

**TL;DR: I would like to get rid of repeating blocks of code.**

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just create a function that you can pass your subview model to that will fill in the repeated parts?

Comment: @MattBurland: Hm... I just tried that, but since `var mappedModel1 = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping1);` results in an array of JSON objects, adding extra properties to that `subModel` just appends them to the array.... Am i misunderstanding your question? Also, having my subModels as observables may have something to do with that....

Comment: where are these variable declared ( like allDirtyItems1, countDirtyItems1, etc) ? I have an idea on how to make this easier but it depends on a few things.  Can you expand your sample to include these variables